# ActiveRecord Mysql Select column as Null

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have this Query :

```
  $this->db->select ( 'u.user_id as id, u.username, u.first_name as firstName, u.last_name as lastName,' . null . 'as client' );
  $this->db->from ( 'users u' );
```

But on executing the same, it says empty column.

Also with

```
  $this->db->select ( 'u.user_id as id, u.username, u.first_name as firstName, u.last_name as lastName, null as client' );
```

It takes null as a column name in users table and reports error as column not found.

Although when executed directly to mysql, the query gives expected output

```
SELECT u.user_id as id, u.username, u.first_name as firstName, u.last_name as lastName, null as client FROM users u
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $this->db->select ( 'u.user_id as id, u.username, u.first_name as firstName, u.last_name as lastName',false);
  $this->db->from ( 'users u' );
```

`false` tells not to escape the query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass FALSE in second parameter of `select()`

```
$this->db->select ( 'u.user_id as id, u.username, u.first_name as firstName, u.last_name as lastName, NULL as client' ,FALSE );
 $this->db->from ( 'users u' );
```